# Get day number from Date format by php

Tags: php

I have a date Formate from database number 2020-11-15 I want to get only the day number. I tried the following.

```
$your_date = '2020-11-15';
$ar_day2 = date("D", strtotime($your_date)); //The value is (Sun)
```

I am looking for result '15'.
Is there way by php?

Answer (score 2):

use small `d`

```
$ar_day2 = date("d", strtotime('2020-11-15'));



echo $ar_day2 = date("d", strtotime('2020-11-15')); // will give =>  15
echo $ar_day2 = date("D", strtotime('2020-11-15')); // will give =>  Sun
```